# Regex for double value with comma

Tags: java, regex

I have below regular expression to validate the double values. This doesn't accept comma. can someone help me on this?

```
^[-+]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

The new regex should accept these values
1000
1,000
1000000.01
1,000,000.00
1.4E-45
3.4028235E38

Comment: Why do you think this regex should accept comma? Which part of it you think is responsible for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^[-+]?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

This is a simple fix - just adds in a 0 or more block of optional comma followed by 3 numbers.

I have also changed the block after your optional decimal to ensure a decimal is followed by at least one number. (so you don't match 52.)

Comment: I'm unsure of your comma rules - you could modify it to specify how many digits must come after a comma (e.g. 3) if you like.

Comment: `(,?[0-9]+)*` should probably be `(,[0-9]{3})*` - note lack of `?` before comma (its optionality will be handled by `)*` part), we don't want to make it optional here since it could make backtracking problematic (not to say catastrophic).

Comment: it works good for this one
^[-+]?(\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)? 

Am i missing anything?

Comment: @skumar, you haven't copied across my modification to your decimal point -> change [.]?[0-9]* to (.[0-9]+)? <- but aside from that it looks like you've just replaced some [0-9] with \d.